# How to add in a relationship in sql management studio with 2 fields

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, relational-database, diagram

Hi right I'm just creating the foriegn keys/relationships in sql server management studio, but I've come across a bit of a problem.
I have several tables lets call them

```
my_form1, 
my_form2, 
my_form3
```

When filling out any of these 'my_forms' I keep a record of that. In another table lets call that 'forms'
In forms I have these fields

```
form_id
form_type - I store the type of form (1,2,3)
myform_id - I store the id of the form.
```

How do I correctly show this on my sql server management relationship.

I've cut down the problem and there are obviously more fields but the situation is the same.

Comment: What is the actual question here? Are you asking how to create foreign keys?

Comment: @SeanLange it sounds like OP wants a foreign key spanning several tables that could have overlapping IDs in the `myform_id` column.  Sounds like maybe a unique constraint on `form_type` and `myform_id`, That's not exactly what OP is asking for, but might be the only option?

Comment: why not just add a column for each form type?

Comment: @Kritner yeah that sounds like it could be the answer, really I'm looking for how do you put this kind of relationship into sql management studio database diagrams, I just really want a line to indicate a relationship - doesn't really need a constraint or a foriegn key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of relationship can't be enforced with a simple foreign key, and therefore won't show up on a diagram generated with SSMS.

You can create your own diagram in Visio and draw it there.   I believe this is what is called a "[Subtype](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=database%20subtype%20entity%20relationship)" entity relationship.

Comment: Ah so you could use visio and reverse engingeer some of the diagram then add relationships like this with Visio.
It's an option - is there another free tool that you know of?

Comment: No, I've always had Visio, so I've never needed to find a free tool.

Comment: Seems like you have hit the nail on the head here, it something that sql management studio can't do and probably why they made Visio. Thankyou for your help.